# Determining PDF of a random vector

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

What is the mathematical rationale for these two lines in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2861973/pdf-transformation-what-manoeuvres-are-involved-in-this-case)?

$$f_{r,\theta}(r,\theta)=\dfrac2\pi f_r(r),\quad r\in(0,R],\quad \theta\in\left(0,\dfrac\pi2\right),$$

then
$$f_z(z)=\dfrac{\,\mathrm dF_z(z)}{\,\mathrm dz} = \dfrac2\pi\int\limits_z^R f_r(r)\dfrac{\mathrm dr}{\sqrt{r^2-z^2}}.$$

For the second line (above), specifically, how was $z$ made the lower limit i.e the transformation to $z$ from $\arccos\dfrac zr$ to derive $\dfrac{\mathrm dr}{\sqrt{r^2-z^2}}$?

Edit: The original transformed function is $$f_r(r)= \frac{2r}{R^{2}}$$

Also $z = r \cos \theta$

I have repeated the diagram here for ease of navigation.

[image]

I see question [a](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/445536/continuous-uniform-distribution-over-a-circle-with-radius-r) and question [b](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/499041/probability-density-of-continuous-uniform-distribution-over-the-unit-circle?rq=1) are a bit close, but I haven't been able to map them to this case yet.

[image: here]

Comment: Clarify.  Define $z$ in terms of $r$ and $\theta$..

Comment: I have made edits to the question. Thank you very much.

Comment: $P(Z\le z)=P(rcos(\theta)\le z)=P(cos(\theta)\le \frac{z}{r})=P(\theta\ge arccos(\frac{z}{r}))$  When you continue from here you will see $z$ as a lower limit.

Comment: I wouldn't mind knowing how to continue from there. What about the $\frac{2}{\pi}$ on the first line? Thanks

Comment: $\frac{2}{\pi}$ is simply a normalization  (the total integral must = 1) for the $\theta$ uniform between $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: Note that $\int_0^Rf_r(r)dr=1$.

Comment: This answer about $\frac{2}{\pi}$ is clear to me now. I appreciate it. But how do I continue from $P(\theta \ge arccos(\frac{z}{r}))$ to get $z$. Thank you

Comment: From the original expression you need to change from $\theta$ to $z$  for integration..$cos(\theta)=\frac{z}{r}$  Therefore $-sin(\theta)d\theta=\frac{dz}{r}$ or $d\theta=\frac{-dz}{\sqrt{r^2-z^2}}$.  You should be able to complete.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you make, it an answer so I can mark as answered correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative approach.  The problem as stated is a disguise for defining $F(z)$ the fraction of the quadrant between $0$ and $z$ and its derivative $f(z)$.  That section of the quadrant is made of two pieces, a triangle with base $z$ and hypotenuse $R$ (area $=T$), and a sector of the circle between that hypotenuse and a vertical radius (area $=S)$.  The total area of the quadrant is $A=\frac{\pi R^2}{4}$.   The other areas are $T=\frac{z\sqrt{R^2-z^2}}{2}$ and $S=\frac{R^2}{2}(\frac{\pi}{2}-arcos{\frac{z}{R}})$.  Thus $F(z)=\frac{S+T}{A}$. To get $f(z)$, we need $\frac{dS}{dz}=\frac{R^2}{2\sqrt{R^2-z^2}}$ and $\frac{dT}{dz}=\frac{R^2-2z^2}{2\sqrt{R^2-z^2}}$  Combining all this to get $f(z)=\frac{4\sqrt{R^2-z^2}}{\pi R^2}$.

The problem as stated sets up the system in polar coordinates and then asks to get $f(z)$ by integrating over $r, \theta$ to get the area fraction $F(z)$.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate this approach. Please at your convenience could you answer the part of [the linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2861973/pdf-transformation-what-manoeuvres-are-involved-in-this-case) with the error function? I really appreciate your contribution. That could also be an answer for the first part of the question.

Comment: One the responses has $F_Z(z)$ as an integral of $f_r(r)$ over polar coordinates.  Change coordinates to $(x,z)$ and integrate out the $x$ should give you the expression you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks herb! Do I need to normalize with $\frac{2}{\pi}$ in this case?

Comment: The expression I refer to has $\frac{2}{\pi}$ in it.  Leave it there. All you need to do is change from $rdrd\theta$ to $dxdz$ and make the needed changes in the integrand.  The upper limit on the $x$ integral is$\sqrt{R^2-z^2}$, leading to the erf term.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am understanding this better now. Still on my pen and paper, at your convenience could I see the full integral. I will be very glad to do the integration myself. Please bear with me, I am not a Pro at transformations yet and I have learned a lot from you. Thank you

Comment: It is hard to make out the contents of the picture.

Comment: I removed the picture. The problem is I now know the upper limit is $\sqrt{R^2-Z^2}$ and $\frac{2}{\pi}$ is involved. But I am struggling with the full integrand. What to integrate? Thank you very much

Comment: You seem to be asking for two problems.  This one where the density is constant over the area.  In your other problem, the density is a truncated normal distribution?  In both cases, you could change from polar to x and z.  Then you need to calculate $F_Z(s)=\int_0^s\int_0^{\sqrt{R^2-z^2}}\frac{f(r)}{r}dxdz$.  The division by $r$ is needed because the polar coordinate differential is $rdrd\theta$.  The integrand is simply replaced by one where $r^2$ is replaced by $x^2+z^2$.

Comment: I hope I am on track: $\frac{-2\lambda}{1-e^{-\lambda \pi R^2/2}}\int_{0}^{S}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{R^2-Z^2}}  \exp{(-\lambda \pi (x^2+z^2)/2)}dx dz$ is what I got. I used $d\theta = \frac{-dz}{\sqrt{r^2-z^2}} = \frac{-dz}{\sqrt{(x^2+z^2)-z^2}} = \frac{-dz}{x}$  and $r=\sqrt{x^2+z^2}; dr=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+z^2}}dx$. I cancelled out the $\pi r$ during the process and retained $\frac{2}{\pi}$. The  negative infront of $\lambda$ is due to the $-dz$

Comment: I hope this is correct but, I am still not sure how $S$ would be eliminated since there is no $S$ in the answer. Very many thanks

Comment: I used s as the upper limit of the integral, since I didn't want to use z, which is the variable for the integration.  s is simply a point on the z axis.  When you take a derivative, you can use z instead - it doesn't matter.

Comment: Your change of variables looks more complicated than necessary.  $dA=rdrd\theta=dxdz$ will do, where $A$ is area.

Comment: Thanks, herb! I hope you don't mind if I make this part separate question on this site and I hope you could answer it there. Despite my frantic efforts, it seems I am getting a bit confused. For instance its not clear to me how you derived $\frac{f(r)}{r}$ . Did you use $\frac{R^2}{2}(\pi/2-\arccos(z/r))$. If yes, how did you manage the part with the $\arccos$? Thanks

Comment: I divided $f(r)$ by $r$ because I wanted to put $r$ as part of the area differential $rdrd\theta$ to facilitate a direct transformation to $dxdz$.

Comment: I don't quite understand your other question.  In setting up the integral over x and z, I used the limits that were appropriate.

Comment: Yep! I think I got it now. So we just integrate $$\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{s}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{R^2-Z^2}} \frac{\lambda \pi r \exp{(-\lambda \pi r^2/2)}}{1-e^{-\lambda \pi R^2/2}}\times \left (\frac{1}{r}\right )dx dz$$ and thats all. I also got the idea of transformation and division by $r$ now. I hope this is correct?

Comment: I got it now. Thank you very much. I observe that changing $r^2=x^2+z^2$ in the exponent and integrating over $\int_{0}^{\sqrt{R^2-Z^2}} dx$ gives the answer without integrating over $\int_{0}^{s} dz$, I am not sure why this is so .

Comment: I have no idea how to navigate chat.  I try to avoid it.  I can't respond to anything in chat.

Comment: I have attached it to the question. y represents $\lambda$ and $v$ represents $R$

Comment: I don't understand this last statement.  Where is this attachment?  As for your previous question, when you integrate over z, you get the cumulative distribution.  Otherwise you get the probability density, which is what you got.

Comment: Thanks for your kind response. The answer is attached below the diagram in this question (I used integral calculator website), above the comments. I learnt so much from you. Quite appreciative

Comment: You seem to have one minor error.  $r$ in the final result should be $R$.

Comment: Yes herb! I couldn't use a capital letter on the calculator. You have done very well and I do not know how well to appreciate your patience, effort and time